# How to detect iOS keyboard 'next' key with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a small SPA written in JS. It has several input fields, but no actual 'form'. Everything is bound with JS.

When the user gets to the last input on a form page, if they press 'tab' or 'enter', I hijack the key event and fire the animation to scroll the next form page in. This all works great.

However, when a user visits on iOS (or android for that matter) if they start filling out inputs and hit the 'next' key, when they reach the end of a form section, the device focuses the next input off screen, and breaks the entire layout, scrolling the viewport in awkward ways and such.

So my question is

1) Is there a way through JS to hijack the 'next' button and properly fire my animations?

or

2) Is there a way to hide the prev/next buttons?

or

3) Is there a way to prevent the 'next' button from jumping to the next section?

I tried making a small jsfiddle that fired an alert on keyup, but the 'next' key doesn't seem to have any sort of keycode, or even to fire the keyup event :/

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try adding hidden dummy input field after the last real field on each page, and going to the next page any time it gets focus.

Comment: This worked totally fine. It feels a little hacky, but hey, it gets the job done.